# Finding an idiomatic way to express a system of linear equations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have an $n$ x $n$ matrix $T$, where $t_{ij}$ is the element at the $i\,$th row and $j\,$th column, and unknowns $x_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, where
$$x_{n} = 1$$
$$x_{n-1} = 0$$
$$x_i = \sum_{1\leq j \leq n}{t_{ij}x_j};\;1\leq i \leq n-2$$
and am trying to package up this problem statement for use in `LinearSolve`. I can get everything working satisfactorily with

```
LinearSolve[T - DiagonalMatrix[Join[Table[1, {n - 2}], {0, 0}]], Append[Table[0, {n - 1}], 1]]
```

but feel like I've made things more complicated than they need to be.

Is there a better, more compact — perhaps more idiomatic — way to express this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit shorter and more expressive:

```
LinearSolve[T - PadRight[IdentityMatrix[n - 2], {n, n}], PadLeft[{1}, n]]
```

Comment: I'm still open to better.

Answer (score 1):

This is but a mild variant. I'll create an example using `n=4`.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 4;
tmat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n - 2, n}]

(* Out[190]= {{-8, 5, -3, -8}, {-4, 2, 4, 2}} *)

LinearSolve[IdentityMatrix[n] - 
  Join[tmat, {ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[0, n]}], UnitVector[n, n]]

(* Out[196]= {18/11, 50/11, 0, 1} *)
```

An alternative might be to use `NullSpace` but then you will need to renormalize based on the last value.

```
NullSpace[IdentityMatrix[n] - Join[tmat, {ConstantArray[0, n], UnitVector[n, n]}]]

(* Out[193]= {{18, 50, 0, 11}} *)
```

Comment: I get errors. And is that even the same thing?

Comment: Anyway, I think [I've found what I was looking for](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65841/37); though I'm open to anything that improves on it.

Comment: How does this relate to `LinearSolve[tmat - DiagonalMatrix[Join[Table[1, {n - 2}], {0, 0}]], Append[Table[0, {n - 1}], 1]]` (from the original question)?

Comment: We've defined the `T` matrix slightly differently. I dropped the last two rows because they do not seem to be used in the formulation of the linear system.